# Is kin punishment compatible with Islamic Law?

Tags: sharia, qisas, murder

Is it correct that kin punishment can be used according to the Sharia? Wikipedia says certain bedouins consider it correct to kill members of the murderer's family, based on the Sharia.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not compatible with Islamic law. Rather it is a pre-Islamic practice which Islam forbade. The practice was that where powerful tribe were victims of murder they would not be satisfied with just executing the murderer but would rather also kill the relatives of the murderer in their rage. Similarly if the murderer could not be caught or was too influential then they instead killed someone else from his tribe as a substitute.

Islam forbids it:

> ولا تقتلوا النفس التي حرم الله إلا بالحق ومن قتل مظلوما فقد جعلنا لوليه سلطانا **فلا يسرف في القتل** إنه كان منصورا
>
> And do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden, except by right. And whoever is killed unjustly - We have given his heir authority, **but let him not exceed limits in [the matter of] taking life**. Indeed, he has been supported [by the law].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:33](https://quran.com/17/33?translations=20)</sup>

> إن أعتى الناس على الله عز وجل من قتل في حرم الله، أو **قتل غير قاتله**، أو قتل بذحول الجاهلية
>
> Three types of people are most hated by Allah, the Almighty: whoever kills another in the Sacred area of Haram (Sanctuary), **whoever kills anyone other than the one who killed him** or whoever kills anyone as revenge for the times of Jahiliyah (pre-Islamic times).
>
> <sup>— [Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/9/23)</sup>

> فقال ابن عباس ، وأكثر المفسرين : معناه لا يقتل غير القاتل وذلك أنهم كانوا في الجاهلية إذا قتل منهم قتيل لا يرضون بقتل قاتله حتى يقتلوا أشرف منه .وقال سعيد بن جبير : إذا كان القاتل واحدا فلا يقتل جماعة بدل واحد وكان أهل الجاهلية إذا كان المقتول شريفا لا يرضون بقتل القاتل [ وحده ] حتى يقتلوا معه جماعة من أقربائه
>
> Ibn Abbas and many of the exegetes said: This means that do not kill anyone other than the murderer. And the practice of the times of ignorance was that when a murder occurred the victim's tribe were not satisfied with killing just the murderer until they had killed someone more reputable than him.
>
> And Sa'id ibn Jubayr said: If the murderer is one man then do not kill a group in-place of the single man. And the practice of the times of ignorance was that if the victim was reputable then his heirs were not satisfied with killing the murderer alone rather they also killed with him a group of his relatives.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://shamela.ws/book/41/1744)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Usually kin punishment or murder happens when some member of family falls in love with a person of different community. This is usually prominent in south east countries like India, Pakistan.

First of all, no body should take law in their hands and inflict punishment on others, even kin. If anyone have complaint against kin, they should report it to authorities who are responsible for law and order. They will do proper investigation and do the needful.

Second, there is no punishement of murder for falling in love with a person of different community or religion. Even though Islam advices Muslim to marry Muslims or people of book and it advices against marriage with polytheist(verse given below), it does not prescribe murder punishment for this.

> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe.1 And a
> believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she
> might please you. And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women]
> until they believe. And a believing slave is better than a polytheist,
> even though he might please you. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but
> Allāh invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And
> He makes clear His verses [i.e., ordinances] to the people that
> perhaps they may remember. [Quran 2:221](https://quran.com/al-baqarah/221)